# Ranorex - work with inputs with binding

Tags: binding, ranorex

Ranorex allows to bind an file with a list of inputs or arguments, to be tested.
I have a file with a list of paths to documents. I want to write a test without binding. I will read the content of the file into a data structure  myself.
Then i want to be able to open the application-under-test (let's say it's Excel), load a file, close the file, close Excel and do this in a loop.
How can i do that ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ranorex is actually nothing more than a .Net extension library you may do almost anything you wish in the bounds of a test.  To do what you want the easiest way is to write a code module that will do this, then simply run it from your test screen.  If you are asking how to read a file in the .Net framework just google it, there are thousands of examples out there